# S tabular with alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

[image]I'm finishing my Msc. Thesis and I'm facing the last problems with some tabular, I'm not able to align this one.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Analisi variabile tasso di interesse\label{tab:stat:tasso}}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\toprule
Data di segnalazione & \makecell[ccc]{\% \\ Tasso di interesse\\ medio} \\
\toprule
2014h1 & 3.59\\
2014h2 & 3.44 \\
2015h1 & 3.37 \\
2015h2 & 3.82 \\
2016h1 & 3.68 \\
\bottomrule
Media & 3.58 \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) what exactly is your question? Not everyone are able to copy and test your code, so it might be a good idea to add an image. (3) You are asking about S tabular alignment, but there are no S columns in this MWE

Comment: I'd like to better align this table with an S tabular alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the reason for 3cm?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Analisi variabile tasso di interesse\label{tab:stat:tasso}}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.2]}
\toprule
\makecell{Data di \\ segnalazione} & 
{\makecell{Tasso di interesse\\ medio (\%)}} \\
\toprule
2014h1 & 3.59\\
2014h2 & 3.44 \\
2015h1 & 3.37 \\
2015h2 & 3.82 \\
2016h1 & 3.68 \\
\midrule
Media & 3.58 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the following output by using an `S` column with th appropriate `table-format` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Analisi variabile tasso di interesse\label{tab:stat:tasso}}
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=1.2]}
\toprule
\makecell[cc]{Data di \\ segnalazione} & {\makecell[cc]{\% \\ Tasso di interesse\\ medio}} \\
\toprule
2014h1 & 3.59\\
2014h2 & 3.44 \\
2015h1 & 3.37 \\
2015h2 & 3.82 \\
2016h1 & 3.68 \\
\bottomrule
Media & 3.58 \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```