# tabular alignment with S

Tags: tables, siunitx

[image]

Thanks for your support in these days of facing problems with `tabular` environment.

I'm not able to understand the way table format works.

I'd like to have a type `S` in the second column of my tabular environment but it doesn't work with subfloat, any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Recovery rate medio per tipo di collateral]{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lp{2cm}}
        \toprule
        Tipo di Collateral & Media Recovery Rate (\%) \\
        \toprule
        No collateral      & 66.80 \\
        Third party plus one other & 88.13 \\
        Two guarantees & 84.67 \\
        Commercial Building & 86.22 \\
        Other Financial Asset & 61.52 \\
        Other Real Estate & 85.76 \\
        Other Vehicles & 59.83 \\
        Residential Building & 92.48 \\
        Securities & 78.70 \\
        Third Party Guarantee & 75.30 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{RRpercollateral:fig:a}               }
\subfloat[Box plot RR per tipo di collateral]{\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth, height=0.45\textwidth]{help2.pdf}
}\\
\caption{Recovery Rate per tipo di collateral}
\label{RRpercollateral_all}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly 'does not work with subfloat'? If you use `S[table-format=2.2]` for the second column and `{\makecell[cc]{Media Recovery \\Rate (\%)}}` for the header of the second column, the alignment in the table should be fine. A similar alignment might even be prdduced by a simple `c` column.

Comment: In an `S` type column everything is tried to be parsed as a number. To protect something from this parsing, enclose it in braces. So in simple words: the table header has to be enclosed by `{}`, to tell `S` that it's not a number. @leandriis did so and additionally used a `\makecell` to introduce a second row in that cell.

Comment: In what way is this different from the suggestion I gave in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436403/4427?

Comment: Ok, it does work, even with subfloat. Thanks

Comment: `table-format=2.2` means that your numbers have 2 integers and 2 decimals.